# Xmppframework for iphone works fine on simulator but not on device?

Tags: iphone, ios4, exc-bad-access, xmppframework

I am trying to see how the xmppframework for iphone works. Everything working perfectly on the simulator but not on device. I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` after it receives the users thats are online.

Any ideas or help?

I have an iPhone 3G ios 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same today with the iPhoneXMPP sample in the iOS simulator.

In XMPPStream.m line 1181, adding the following check seems to fix it for me :

```
            if (myPresence!=presence)
            {
                [myPresence release];
                myPresence = [presence retain];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**From Apple documentation.**

> This kind of problem is usually the
>   result of over-releasing an object. It
>   can be very confusing, since the
>   failure tends to occur well after the
>   mistake is made. The crash can also
>   occur while the program is deep in
>   framework code, often with none of
>   your own code visible in the stack.

[More](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1367/_index.html)

Check the below SO post

[EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received)

[How do i resolve EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors encountered in iphone development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607222/how-do-i-resolve-exc-bad-access-errors-encountered-in-iphone-development)

[how to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iPhone](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: Hello thank you very much i will try to see into it :) Thanks again, i will try to use NSZombie enables and see where its bugging.