# Why don't need deallocation some objects?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If I allocated memory for any objects, sometimes I must run deallocate. 
But if I declare variable (for example NSString) and don't allocate as below:

```
NSString* myStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"file.xml" ....];
```

Why I catch error if I try deallocate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringWithContentsOfFile` is a convenience method of NSString that takes care of it.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607222/how-do-i-resolve-exc-bad-access-errors-encountered-in-iphone-development/4581151#4581151) for an explanation of what you do and do not need to release.